# Android 2.2 won't start

Tags: android

I'm collecting all the RPi OS that o can because some of them have functions and  apps that others haven't, and I think that it can be useful.
Recently I've created a SD with last Android image on their website, but when I put RPi working, just show me prompt screen and next just dark screen during all the time that it keep on.

Comment: whose website? which android release? could we have a link?

Comment: We really could use a link to the build you are using (which would provide us with the version), the instructions you are following, and the version of your Raspberry Pi (Model A/B and year.) That would help us a lot.

Answer (score 1):

How far you'll get with any android release depends on the version of the release and the type of Raspberry Pi you have.

You can find most of the details over at [The Android Pi wiki](http://androidpi.wikia.com/wiki/Android_Pi_Wiki)

You will find that depending on those factors your mileage may vary.

Besides this, there isn't really a publically available android build that will run on the RPI behaving decently.

All of them lack core features and/or are *terribly* slow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the Gingerbread image build circa beginning of the last year, it won't work on the recent Raspbery Pi's, probably because of different memory size and other hardware changes introduced since then.

Might work on early 256MB models, perhaps.

Comment: My RPi is model A and i'm using RCA video because HDMI won't work too.